gitlab - terraform - how to souce terraform modules without hard coding gitlab token
I am using terraform , this is a sample from my main.tf , which is working.
    module "params" {   
source = "git::https://terraform-modules:sdp-example12567ghhdsh@gitlab.abc.xyz.com/abcd/ty245653/test/terraform-modules/param-store.git?ref=v1.0.1"
 env              = var.key
 tags             = var.tags
 }

sdp-example12567ghhdsh is example gitlab token. I have been told to not hardcode gitlab token in the source. I have tried several ways of not using it, like using variable or something, but its not working. I am not able to find a working example anywhere.
The gitlab repo is private enterprise repo.
Please suggest any ways this can be done.

Per the documentation https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#generic-git-repository "Terraform installs modules from Git repositories by running git clone, and so it will respect any local Git configuration set on your system, including credentials. To access a non-public Git repository, configure Git with suitable credentials for that repository."

@MarkB There is nothing set on the system. Its an enterprise gitlab , code is run on gitlab runners. So any credentials need to come from the code itself.

You would need to set the Git credentials inside the GitLab runner task, before calling terraform.
